# How To Show Assistant Editor in Right Side

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

In My `Xcode` My `Assistant Editor` is Showing into the **Bottom** of Xcode But all other Xcode in another system it will b showing in **right side** then how can i put my xcode assistant Editor into bottom to right side of xcode...

[image]

Answer (score 13):

select your `Xcode` menu `View` button

select  `Assistant Editor`  and change the mode

[image]

Comment: I had my Assistant Editor selected and the file on the right was appearing blank. I fixed it by going to View > Assistant Editor > Reset Editor. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode 11.5 (and above) use this popup menu:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of Xcode this has changed. As of 11.3 it's now `View -> Change Editor Orientation`:

[image]